# How do I change only what "dd" does in evil-mode's normal-state in a minor mode

Tags: key-bindings, evil

When I press <kbd>dd</kbd> in `haskell-interactive-mode` at the prompt, it doesn't delete anything, because part of the line is read-only. I would like to map <kbd>dd</kbd> to `'haskell-interactive-mode-kill-whole-line`.

this

```
(evil-define-key 'normal haskell-interactive-mode-map
  (kbd "dd") 'haskell-interactive-mode-kill-whole-line)
```

doesn't solve the problem. Although it binds <kbd>dd</kbd>, it clobbers evil-mode's <kbd>d</kbd> binding, making commands like <kbd>dw</kbd> no longer work. Just adding things to the `evil-operator-shortcut-map` (like what evil-surround does) doesn't quite cut it either, because that would bind nonsensical sequences like <kbd>yd</kbd> which should remain unbound.

[These](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/9394/6761) [two](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.vim-emulation/2000) links are relevant, but not quite answers.

Comment: `yd`? What does that do?

Comment: Nothing, as it should.

Comment: If you are still interested, I can immediately post a high-quality solution.  Would you open bounty for that?

Comment: Sure. It's not like I'm using that reputation for anything anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial idea to merely remap `dd` has another subtle issue.  As you surely know `Vd` is basically the same as `dd` (in a sense that it operates on a whole line), so it should also exhibit the same desired behavior somehow (i.e. use `haskell-interactive-mode-kill-whole-line` as a back end).  I hope it's clear that this also applies to an infinite set of other possibilities: `10dd`, `Vjjjd`, and etc.  Hence, we are going to define our own `haskell-delete` operator (thanks to the Evil framework facilities):

```
(evil-define-operator haskell-delete
    (beg end type register yank-handler)
  "Delete text from BEG to END with TYPE.
Save in REGISTER or in the kill-ring with YANK-HANDLER."
  (interactive "<R><x><y>")
  (if (eq type 'line)
      (progn
        (unless register
          (let ((text (filter-buffer-substring beg end)))
            (unless (string-match-p "\n" text)
              (evil-set-register ?- text))))
        (let ((evil-was-yanked-without-register nil))
          (evil-yank beg end type register yank-handler))
        (dotimes (var (count-lines beg end))
          (haskell-interactive-mode-kill-whole-line)))
    (evil-delete beg end type register yank-handler))
  (when (and (evil-called-interactively-p)
             (eq type 'line))
    (evil-first-non-blank)))
```

And now simply remap `d` in `haskell-interactive-mode-map` specific to the Normal state:

```
(evil-define-key 'normal haskell-interactive-mode-map
  (kbd "d") #'haskell-delete)
```

Please, let me know if you encounter any issues, so that we could jointly fix them.

Comment: That looks like it will work. I'll try it and get back to you.

Comment: This seems to work; the only problem is that it puts the point at the beginning of the line rather than at the end. Replacing `(evil-first-non-blank)` with `(evil-end-of-line)` solves that. Would you consider explaining your operator definition so that I could write my own for `yy` and `cc`?

Comment: Simply take a look at what `evil-delete` does.  The part with `register` dancing is there to handle yanking of what you delete (same way the default `evil-delete` does, thus this code is copy/paste from it).  The loop simply solves the problem when several lines are involved.  The very last part with `evil-first-non-black` is again copy/paste from `evil-delete` (i.e. that's how default delete operator is expected to function, hence your choice of `evil-end-of-line` looks weird to me).  The condition on whether `type` is `'line` distinguishes the case where we want to apply operator to line(s).

Comment: `evil-first-non-blank` puts the point before the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the right way to map operators is using `evil-operator-state-map`. So this

```
(defun my-haskell-maps() 
  (define-key evil-operator-state-local-map
  "D" 'haskell-interactive-mode-kill-whole-line))

(add-hook 'haskell-interactive-mode-hook 'my-haskell-maps)
```

will map `dD` to the correct function without interfere with the other `d` operators. However, for some reason, mapping `dd` does not work. Maybe because it doesn't override evil defaults. I'll let you know if I manage to fix the `dd` binding

Comment: It's probably because evil hardcodes repetition of the operator as a line-wise operation, hacking around that will be more involved than your snippet I'm afraid.

Comment: The relevant portion of the code that defines "dd" (albeit indirectly) is: https://gitorious.org/evil/evil/source/ff74cfbf50faf55971891dcbbbde2c0b66799ac4:evil-macros.el#L511