# Evil virtual textobjects

Tags: evil

I'm working on a textobject based on `ffap-guesser`. I'd like for <kbd>yif</kbd> to yank the `file-at-point`. This works great, except when there is no literal file at point, and `ffap` is doing some of it's more creative guessing.

For example. Running `ffap-guesser` on

```el
(require 'config-company)
```

Yields `"/home/pythonnut/.emacs.d/modules/config-company.el"`. Ideally, <kbd>yif</kbd> would yank that string instead of what's in the buffer.

I mostly care about yanking, but obviously it would be cool if this worked for other operators. (Deleting, for example, would delete the range that `ffap-guesser` used to guess?)

Can this be done reasonably?

Comment: What would you expect `dif` to delete in that example?

Comment: Whatever `ffap` used to guess said filename, I suppose.

Comment: I bet people would find a text object `f` confusing if `dif` deleted different text from that which `yif` yanked.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember right, you sometimes use [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles).

If so, then anytime you are in the minibuffer, you can use **`M-.`** to insert text from the buffer, at point, or in fact text derived from that text. Page [**Inserting Text from Cursor**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Inserting_Text_from_Cursor) of the **Icicles** doc describes this feature.

The behavior of `M-.` is governed by user options [**`icicle-thing-at-point-functions`** and **`icicle-default-thing-insertion`**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Customization_and_General_Tips#icicle-thing-at-point-functions).

In particular, if library `ffap.el` is loaded then option `icicle-thing-at-point-functions` includes **`ffap-guesser`** as one of its text-grabbing functions.

This means that you can use `M-.` to grab `/home/pythonnut/.emacs.d/modules/config-company.el` into the minibuffer when the cursor is on the library name `config-company` in the buffer text `(require 'config-company)`.

You can customize `icicle-thing-at-point-functions` to move the position of `ffap-guesser` sooner or later in the list of text-grabbing functions that are used when you use `M-.` repeatedly.

---

**Updated after your comment -**

So are you asking for a command that copies to the  `kill-ring` what `ffap-guesser` returns at point?  If so, try this:

```el
(defun ffap-guesser-copy (&optional msgp)
  "..."
  (interactive "p")
  (let ((text  (kill-new (ffap-guesser))))
    (when msgp (message "Copied `%s to kill ring" text))))

(global-set-key "\C-o" 'ffap-guesser-copy)
```

Comment: That's neat, and thanks for the tip; that binding looks super useful. However, my most common use-case for this textobject is actually copying the file path to external programs by way of the clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

What you're proposing isn't really a text object.  To recap:

> Text objects are defined with `evil-define-text-object`. In Visual
>   state, they modify the current selection; in Operator-Pending state,
>   they return a pair of buffer positions. Outer text objects are bound
>   in the keymap `evil-outer-text-objects-map`, and inner text objects
>   are bound in `evil-inner-text-objects-map`.
>
> Common text objects like words, WORDS, paragraphs and sentences are
>   defined via a corresponding move-function. […]

The definition of a text object as movement means that it must be part of the buffer to allow each Evil operator to work upon it.  If you look at the arguments of `evil-delete` for example, you'll notice the first two are BEG and END.

Therefore I can only imagine the approach of overloading the operators you have in mind to work.  [It isn't nearly as easy to do as in Vim](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9389/map-a-key-to-an-evil-operator-and-to-other-things) (where you just override a mapping with your custom command and are done), but still possible.